# Find last element on every row in a textfile and sum them if it´s a value and it´s even?

Tags: python, element, slice

I need some help with finding last element on every row in a textfile that is about 1000rows or more. When they are finded I want to check if they are even integers. If they are I want to add them to "sum". Anyone got an idea in how i can fix this?

```
fhand = open('textfile.txt')
sum= 0
int(a)

for line in fhand:
    a = (line[-1:])
    sum = sum + a


print(sum)
```

Am I on right track? How would you solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: Define *last element*?

Comment: can you show an example line ?

Comment: Fix indentation, and provide exact error you are getting. The code you've posted does not work at all.

Comment: @Kasra Something like this: "194.132.30.254 - - [02/Jul/2014:16:04:47 +0200] "GET /img/glyphicons/png/glyphicons_382_youtube.png HTTP/1.1" 200 375"

Comment: @kroolik Yes, I know that. But im just posting that code to explain how my idea is. I know that that code doesnt work at all! You know how I can solve this?

Comment: I bet my pants that kroolik does know "how to solve this" if only you show us what you really want. Maybe you don't realize it but what you asked is not univocal.  Further, posting not working code (with a hint to static typing too!;) doesn't cast a good image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `try/except`:

```
with open('textfile.txt') as f:
    total = 0 # don't use sum as it shadows the builtin sum function
    for line in f:
        try:
            a = int(line.rstrip()[-1]) # get very last character
            if a % 2 == 0:
                total += a
        except ValueError:
            pass

print(total)
```

Comment: @gboffi, no it is there in the try

Comment: @gboffi what do you think `if a % 2 == 0` is doing?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham   Thanks man! =) They are not separeted by whitespace. A line in the textfile looks like this: "194.132.30.254 - - [02/Jul/2014:16:04:47 +0200] "GET /img/glyphicons/png/glyphicons_382_youtube.png HTTP/1.1" 200 375" So in this case I want to look at the five and see if that´s even. I get exactly what you mean. But will it be wrong now without that whitespace?

Comment: is it only the very last digit that you always want?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thanks alot.  I´ve been stuck on that one for hours. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
with open('textfile.txt') as f:
    last_element = [line.split()[-1] for line in f] # when the file is not very large.

total = sum([int(e) for e in last_element if e.isdigit() and int(e) % 2 == 0])

print total
```

Comment: `-12` is also a number